# Estoy buscando la forma de obtener los valores rgb de un input color, para despues colocarlos en la funcion php = "imagecolorallocate"

Tags: php, html

lo que estoy programando es colocar textos dentro de una imagen, y la funcion "imagecolorallocate" solo acepta numeros enteros.  o si conocen otra forma se los agradeceria

```
<?php
if ( $_GET['color'], $_GET['texto1'], $_GET['texto2'], $_GET['texto3'])) {
    $color = ($_GET['color']);    
    $textoo1 = ($_GET['texto1']);
    $textoo2 = ($_GET['texto2']);
        $textoo3 = ($_GET['texto3']);

}

$imagen = imagecreatefrompng($nombreImagen);
$color = imagecolorallocate($imagen, 0, 0, 0);//// Esta es la funcion que estoy ocupando para arrojar los textos, los numeros es onde quiero arrojar el valor le input color;
$texto1 = $_GET["texto1"];
$texto2 = $_GET["texto2"];
$texto3 = $_GET["texto3"];
    
header("Content-Type: image/png");
imagepng($imagen);
imagedestroy($imagen);
```

Comment: Agrega el código para ver que intentaste y como te podemos ayudar

Comment: Subi el codigo php, Es para insertar textos dentro de una imagen, pero la funcion imagecolorallocate, pide como parametros los 3 valores numericos de un rgb
y lo que yo quiero es que el input color, me guarde los varoles rgb, para poder mandarselos a la funcion php